# Flutter Firebase Notification issue Android

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) in my flutter application. On **Android Integration** when i write native Application level code i get errors.

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

class Application: FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }
    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
    }
}
```

> Unresolved Reference: FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
>
> TypeMismatch: Required **FlutterEngine**. Found **PluginRegistry?**

I have successfully added Google-services.json under my app folder also added the required dependencies in the project level gradle and app level gradle currently i am using

**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.3'**

Version.

**Flutter Details:**
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale en-US)
Firebase_messaging version is ^6.0.12

I have even tried to downgrade the version of firebase-Messaging but still found this problem.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Sadly no, i had to use older older version of this package (firebase_messaging)

Comment: ok, but you could have replace your registerWith() function with following code:
override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) { registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"); }
This should have solve your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your Application.kt class just modify the function:

```
 override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
          }
```

Comment: Thanks @harpeetSeera for the answer. Needed to know is this a kotlin issue, or this library issue??

Comment: it's neither kotlin issue nor library issue, it's just that we need to register the plugin to use it.

Comment: what about firebase_messaging: "^9.0.0"? It's now changed

Answer (score 0):

Cut method `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)` in your Application's `registerWith;`
and paste it into your `MainActivity`'s method `configureFlutterEngine`, like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

    }
}
```

PS:
 I got a new Unhandled Exception (doesn't affect FCM function, but looks ugly; I'm working on it):

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method FcmDartService#initialized on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging_background)
```